# Discord Bot problem with "get_all_members()" function in python

Tags: python, discord, bots

What I wanted was for it to collect the information of all the users in the server for referencing using **get_all_members()**. Currently the bot just collects the details of itself instead of everyone in the server.
Is there anyway to fix this?

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     for member in bot.get_all_members():
             print(member.name)
             print(member.id)
```

The output currently is:

```
AllSeeingEye
746569829267275866
```

Comment: [You don't have Member Intents enabled.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=member%20intents)

Comment: Thank you for the help, there was also some OAuth2 stuff I had to do. The interesting part is the program did work about a week ago without needing the OAuth2 and intents. Also it says that "discord" has no class "Intent".

Comment: The API change was recent. It's using a new gateway. You can downgrade your discord.py version then it's using the old gateway and it will work like before but the old gateway will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's all good now.

Comment: Idk if the question is still up, but I have some struggle with it too. How exactly cant I get it work, that  get_all_members() returns all members and not just it self @RavsterGuy